# Chrome changes URL case

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrom 66.0.3359.139 on Mac OSX.

I have a URL that includes a variable resource which is case sensitive. It looks like this.

http://example.com/find/resource

I wanted to change the case on the URL to identify a different resource. The change looks like this.

http://example.com/find/Resource

The problem I'm having is that Chrome changes it back to a lowercase r before making the request.

How can I tell Chrome to actually make the request I type in rather than changing the case of the URL?

Answer (score 14):

I just dealt with the same issue. Adding a trailing '/' stopped Chrome from changing the url for me. For example:

http://example.com/find/Resource/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works for some pages, but other pages don't work with the trailing slash, such as wiki pages

Answer (score 10):

The same thing happened to me. This happened because I called the URL with lowercase before. After removing the calls in Chrome's history, the case wasn't changed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was similar. Users in the app I am developing were provided a computer generated link which worked fine. But if the user needed to manually return to the page, the right-most part of the link was capitalized.

The problem seems to have been that earlier in testing, initial capitals were used and the "smart" url field-reader inserted the old address instead of the new one. I think the problem was really DuckDuckGo, not Chrome, because when I disabled DDG, all was well. Initially I was pretty sure the problem was with Chrome because Safari did not fail.