# Chrome changes entered urls to lowercase

Tags: google-chrome, url

We are in 2024 and still have the problem in chrome browser mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298340/chrome-changes-url-case). But no answer were proposed at the time.

Version of chrome 120.0.6099.217

This is very problematic since I'm working on an app requiring case sensitive urls. The problem seems to occur when the url has already been accessed with the wrong case and the user retries with the good one (history issue).
Ex:

1. The user navigates to http://test.com/**mypersonalspace**/login but he forgot the url was case sensitive
2. He enters again the url with good case http://test.com/**MyPersonalSpace**/login
3. Chrome decides to pick up the url from history and rewrite the url with case from 1.

This is problematic for many reasons. Do you know if there is a workaround ?

The question here is not to know if the url must be case sensitive or not the question is why a browser used by a lot of people do not follow standards. Feels like a bug to me.

Regarding the problem, I'm expecting Chrome to behave like the other browsers on the market. FF or Safari for example which are dealing fine with this. I tried to deactivate all my extensions without any success...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not something I can reproduce. Can you see any redirects in the Network tab of the Developer Tools?

Comment: Unsure how your question is suitable for SO and what you are expecting here?

Comment: @DarkBee aside from this being a dupe, this is squarely within the site's scope and is a question of standards (and thus expectations and guarantees).

Comment: How is it? "*I'm expecting Chrome to behave like the other browsers on the market*" - Does OP wants to fix/patch Chrome?

Comment: @DarkBee not sure of what do you express in your comment. Tell me if I'm wrong, and I surely am, but the standards allow to have case sensitive urls at least for the path part. So why is there such a behavior on Chrome ? I don't want to fix/patch Chrome I just want to understand why they didn't implement the standard behavior and also how can we propose apps using case sensitive urls with such. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ivar I will try to dig deeper since you tell me u cannot reproduce it it means it is specific to my config.

Comment: I'm just pointing out your question is not suited for SO. If you have specific questions/problems with Chrome, then please open a ticket/thread on their [community page](https://support.google.com/chrome/community?sjid=6330934018428596414-EU)

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED Thanks for your comment. Doest it mean that I should have posted a comment directly on the post I mentionned ? Since it is very old I thought it was better to open a new one but nevermind. Sorry for that then. My post has been closed with a proposal for another post and I don't really see how this answers my question :(

Comment: @DarkBee ok since I'm developping web apps and I'm blocked by an annoying behavior of one my dev tools (chrome) I thought it was a good place to post my question. Moreover  this question was already asked with no answers so... But you are right I should have posted directly on chrome com page.